# Hosting Ghost blog without NginX or Apache

Tags: node.js, apache, nginx, ghost-blog

I've decided to take the plunge and make my next blog in Ghost 0.4.1 rather than Wordpress. My client has a VERY small amount of traffic, and it is easy to say that they will never need to be load balanced across multiple servers.

**My question is:**
Ghost can be configured to listen to a certain port, so can I use it as my web server listening to port 80? Is there a problem to doing this?

**Followup Question:**
Every example shows hosting it with Apache or NginX, is there a security or performance reason for this?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You definitely can run Ghost on port 80 but it is recommended to run Ghost on port 2368 and proxy requests through Apache or Nginx.

You can checkout [this](http://www.howtoinstallghost.com/how-to-setup-bluehost-vps-for-ghost-blog/) article for an example of how to install Ghost and run it on port 80.  But I would highly recommend reading through [this article](http://www.allaboutghost.com/how-to-proxy-port-80-to-2368-for-ghost-with-nginx/) and proxying requests through Nginx.  With Ghost running on port 2368 you can use a low privileged user to start Ghost and therefore will not have to use a higher privileged user to start Ghost.

Comment: I know you! You're the guy who bought up all the ghost domains in the hope of getting referral money. Good luck spamming all the ghost posts to drive up your SEO ranking!

Answer (score 0):

Yes. But you must run Ghost under root privilege or add ghost to sudoers

```
  server: {
            host: '0.0.0.0',
            port: '80'
        }
```

I tried and it worked.